# How does Boolberry's Wild Keccak work?

Tags: boolberry, proof-of-work

Boolberry uses an algo named Wild Keccak. This is refered to as a blockchain based POW. How does this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a high-level description of this algorithm at http://cpucoinlist.com/cryptocurrency-algorithms/wild-keccack/ which reports as follows:

> Wild Keccak is a Keccak hybrid which uses blockchain data as
>   scratchpad. After each Keccak round, pseudo-randomly addressed [state
>   vector used as addresses] data is taken from scratchpad and XORed with
>   state. Calculating each block PoW usually hits about 1100 randomly
>   addressed reading of blocks by 32 bytes.